# How to replace ANSI characters with UTF-8 characters and save the document in UTF-8 format?

Tags: powershell, utf-8, ansi

I tried running this:

```
(Get-Content c:\example.srt).replace('æ', 'ć') | Set-Content c:\example.srt
```

But it only replaces the character `æ` with ANSI `c`.

I'd also like to be able to replace more than 1 character at the time.

Comment: This seems like an XY Problem. When does a  human want to replace 'æ' with 'ć'? What are you really trying to do? And, which ANSI encoding is the source? Surely, it is not always the script runner's console's encoding at the time the script is run.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

Replace them in the character group.Put the symbols in the character group.

```
Get-Content c:\example.srt |% {$_ -replace "[æ\._\.*]", "ć"}
```

It will replace `æ` , `_` , `*` with `ć`.

like:

```
Get-Date -Format G | foreach {$_ -replace "[:\./]", "_"}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, these are the 4 ANSI characters i need to replace with 4 UTF-8 characters: "È" with "Č", "è" with "č", "æ with "ć", and "ð" with "đ" (First two are uppercase).

Now i tried to run this bellow and it replaces character but with another ANSI character (it replaces "æ" with "c" instead of ć, same thing goes for the other characters, it assigns another 'equivalent' ASCI character instead of UTF-8 one..:  



`(Get-Content c:\example.srt) |% {$_ -replace "È", "Č"}  | Set-Content c:\example.srt`

Comment: you can actually change the encoding type in notepad++

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't display/change these characters properly. So far the only way was to do the character replacement manually in windows notepad, but it's a lot of hassle as you can imagine. Could it be that i just have to enable UTF-8 support somewhere in powershell?

Comment: You used it improperly...I updated the example to include your path

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a go. It converts a file from [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) to [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

```
$ansi = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)

Get-Content -Encoding $ansi "c:\example.srt" | Out-File -Encoding UTF-8 "c:\example.srt"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i get: `Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.`

Comment: (I was running: `Get-Content -Encoding $ansi $example.srt | Out-File -Encoding UTF-8 $example.srt`)