# Powershell replaces special characters

Tags: html, powershell, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I have a powershell script to insert som text into a .html document. However as I live in Denmark I have a big problem. I'm inserting "æ" "ø" "å" both in and without caps. Powershell replaces these letters with "xE6" "xF8" "xE5". HTML makes this look like this: �

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Current scripts:

First .bat file

```
echo off
set /p Date="Date: "
set /p Location="Location: "
set /p Amount="Amount: "

powershell -command "(Get-Content Name_of_file.html) -replace 
'Text that gets replaced, using the variables up top' | Set-Content 
Name_Of_File.html"
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File replace_quot.ps1
exit
```

replace_quot.ps1 file

```
(Get-Content Name_of_File.html) -replace '&quot;', '"' | set-content 
Name_of_File.html
```

But as i said if i insert æ ø or å it will not insert them currectly.

Link to my first post just incase you need more context: [Add a string of text into a html document using cmd/batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792265/add-a-string-of-text-into-a-html-document-using-cmd-batch-file)

I hope I explained this well enough, if there was something you didn't understand then just write, then I'll try to clarify.

Charset is UTF-8

Comment: What is the [charset](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp) of the HTML file as this determines which [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) is used for the text data inside the HTML file? In case of you don't know anything about character encoding, especially in HTML files, read [this topic](http://forums.ultraedit.com/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=17598) in UltraEdit user-to-user forum.

Comment: I believe this is the line you are looking for:      <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: So my supposition was right. You have declared the HTML file as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded, but inserted the text [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoded. You can change `charset` declaration to `<meta charset="Windows-1252">` and of course make sure the rest of the HTML file is really Windows-1252 encoded which is most likely the case as containing only ASCII characters. Then you have nothing to change on the script. Otherwise you have to convert the text from Windows-1252 to UTF-8 before inserting it into the HTML file.

Comment: For the second solution see for example [How to replace ANSI characters with UTF-8 characters and save the document in UTF-8 format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567231/) found with Stack Overflow search with search term [\[powershell\] convert Windows-1252 UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+convert+Windows-1252+UTF-8).

Comment: For the Windows PowerShell interpreter to see your unicode codepoints properly, you need to save your script using UTF8 WITH BOM, otherwise the parser defaults to ANSI encoding.  This issue was remedied by defaulting to UTF8 (non-bom) in PowerShell Core.  [Here's an answer I gave recently on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52106439/encoding-issue-piping-value-to-command/52106696#52106696)

Comment: The `Set-Content` cmdlet has a `-Encoding` option. `help Set-Content -Full`